# camera programming in black berry

Tags: blackberry

my following code returns null ,

```
byte[] image1 = _videoControl.getSnapshot(null);
```

any suggestion please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few important moments about VideoControl.getSnapshot method:

- some manufacturers may not implement getSnapshot() method;
- the viewfinder must actually be visible on the screen prior to calling getSnapShot();
- if you attempt to take pictures too quickly, however, getSnapShot() may
  return null. The camera requires time to clear out its buffer and
  prepare for the next shot;
- you may check MMAPI System Property for "video.snapshot.encodings" before capturing:

```
if (System.getProperty("video.snapshot.encodings") == null) {
        // getSnapshot() is not supported
}
```

You may read this chapter from book "Advanced BlackBerry Development":
http://books.google.com/books?id=F4Qu-lpoVncC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: This is really helpful... Thanks for the pin point answer in the link, i.e. In all cases, the viewfinder must actually be visible on the screen prior to calling getSnapShot(), just make your Field focusable, and will get a byte[] in return. Gr8 answer...

Answer (score 0):

Since `VideoControl.getSnapshot` method is not supported by all devices I'd recommend to use another approach. You can start the native BB Camera app with this line of code:

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_CAMERA, new CameraArguments());
```

and then using the `FileSystemJournalListener` catch the taken image.

The BB SDK on your PC contains samples. Search for 'fileexplorerdemo' sample to see the rest of details.